# JQuery, CSS and hover tag re-code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.social-icon-holder {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.social-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /*  background: #000;*/
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.social-icon:hover {
  color: #fff;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.social-icon:hover .front {
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.social-icon:hover .back {
  -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.social-icon .front,
.social-icon .back {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.social-icon .back {
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.social-icon .twitter .back {
  background: #00ACED;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-icon-holder">
  <div class="social-icon">
    <div class="twitter">
      <div class="front">t</div>
      <div class="back">t</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mcc3267g/)

I did not produce the majority of the code.

The icon flips/rotates when a user hovers over the icon.
I realize this is done via the `hover` class.

However I would like to trigger this animation manually (via an event etc).

I understand it is not possible to trigger `hover` as it is not a trusted event.

Can someone help me re-code this so that the animation is triggered via jQuery?

Comment: If you only want to apply the effect manually and never through hover, try moving the hover css into a simple class and swap classes with JavaScript/jQuery? Try that and check out jQuery [**addClass**](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/), [**remove**](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) which should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css where you set the hover states, you could add a selector that does the same for a specific class. In my example I added the class `hover`, so the line `.social-icon:hover` now becomes `.social-icon:hover, .social-icon.hover` etc.

You can then toggle this class using jQuery's `.toggleClass()` function.

In the below example I do this using a button and a `click` event.

*I added a background color just so the icon is more visible, so this has nothing to do with the actual answer ;)*

```js
$('#triggerHover').on('click', function() {
  $('.social-icon').toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
body {
 background: #ccc;
}

.social-icon-holder {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.social-icon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /*  background: #000;*/
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}

.social-icon:hover, .social-icon.hover {
  color: #fff;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.social-icon:hover .front, .social-icon.hover .front {
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.social-icon:hover .back, .social-icon.hover .back {
  -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.social-icon .front,
.social-icon .back {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.social-icon .back {
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.social-icon .twitter .back {
  background: #00ACED;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social-icon-holder">
  <div class="social-icon">
    <div class="twitter">
      <div class="front">t</div>
      <div class="back">t</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="triggerHover">Click me!</button>
```